# dplyr: how to make copies of rows with one difference based on different columns?

Tags: r, dplyr

my data currently looks like this:

```
|Temp | Sex | ID | Survival1 | Surival11 | Survival21 |
|- - -|-----|----|-----------|-----------|------------|
| 30  | Male| 1  |    1      |     1     |     0      |


But I'm trying to make it so that I create 3 rows with Temp/Sex/ID the same but each of the survival columns added on to look like this with a time column

|Temp | Sex | ID | Time | Survival | 
|- - -|-----|----|------|-----------|
| 30  | Male| 1  |  1   |    1      |   
| 30  | Male| 1  |  11  |    1      |
| 30  | Male| 1  |  21  |    0      |
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done neatly with the `tidyr` package:

```
d <- data.frame(Temp = 30, Sex = "Male", ID = 1, Survival1 = 1, Survival11 = 1, Survival21 = 0)

d |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(Survival1:Survival21,
                      values_to = "Survival", 
                      names_to = "Time",
                      names_pattern = "Survival(.*)")
```